# Why does this code give me an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop

When I enter in a correct value (an integer) it is good. But when I enter in a character, I get an infinite loop. I've looked at every side of this code and could not find a problem with it. Why is this happening? I'm using g++ 4.7 on Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int n;
    while (!(std::cin >> n))
    {
        std::cout << "Please try again.\n";
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
    }
}
```

Input: `x`
Output:

[image]

Comment: is there an unprintable character like CR coming along with the input when you type or does `cin` grab one character?

Comment: Just use `scanf`. Way easier and clearer.

Comment: @Joker_vD But I thought this was C++...

Comment: `scanf` is never the right answer. To anything.

Comment: @qwrrty Well, `scanf` is marginally faster than `cin >>` (not sure why, it has to parse the format string), so if the question is "performance!1!!11elevenone", it may be the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your recover operations are in the wrong order. First clear the error then clear the buffer.

```
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't even tell! :)

Comment: The point is that because the stream is in an error state `ignore` will also fail unless you clear the error first.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `clear` the error state first, and *then* `ignore` the unparsable buffer content. Otherwise, `ignore` will do nothing on a stream that's not in a good state.

You will separately need to deal with reaching the end of the stream.